# Beginners guide for biblatex BY EXAMPLE

Tags: biblatex

I decided to turn the original question into several questions and simplified the basic one. Many thanks to Alan Munn.

I would like to use biblatex, however I found no simple guide for beginners BY EXAMPLE.

I read this [Biblatex guide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64907), but it is not by example.

[This](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/bibliography/) guide, which I found in this question: [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091) in the last answer, does not concentrate on the following.

At first I thought this question [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509) might help, but it doesn't really do that.

I hope there is someone who is willing to pick up the gauntlet and create a simple guide by example, without general option, but with many sample different types of citations really written. (Feel free to revise the question top to bottom in order to provide the simplest guide for beginners as an answer. I'm willing to contribute as much as I can)

The bibliography is in a `.bib` file, of course.

My own citation style needs are rather traditional. I need a simple author-year like AuthorLastName (1995). I can use a possessive version of citation: AuthorLastName's (1995)  (the   's should be added by a suitable command). Parentheses citation (ALN (1995)) might be easy to achieve manually if it is complicated. From time to time multiple authors citation like AuthorLastName, ALN2 and ALN3(2001) may be found helpful, as multiple authors by the first author last name like  ALN et al. (2002) should be available. Multiple citations for the same author(s): ALN (2003,2004) looks like an integral part.

Anyone?

Comment: Your title says BibTeX but all of the links are about `biblatex`: which is it you are after?

Comment: I'm still not really clear on what you want: I think you want details for creating/modifying `biblatex` style files (`.bbx`/`.cbx`) rather than the 'user' part of what to put in your LaTeX sources. However, I'm not sure how 'by example' helps here: it's not a short topic as there are so many variables.

Comment: I'm curious about this citation style.  What field/journal is it used in?

Comment: @joseph-wright - I am after a simple (without many options) \cite like related commands. the basic commands like \usepackage{biblatex} should be included in an example of course. The asterisk option is a specific need of mine, that might be written in a different question. I wish to avoid external files (you mentioned `.bbx` / `.cbx` which I am not familiar with)

Comment: @alan-munn - it is not for a specific journal. Similar styles are used in economics. I am a beginner and I have been straggling with several bibliography styles (papers based on older ones templates). I need a quick way in, and I will learn how to manage with the options later. I am positive that such guide may help to many.

Comment: As Joseph says, this is a non-trivial question, and the combination of a numbered and author/year citations is very unorthodox (hence my question to you).  A better way for you to ask your question might be to get an example document that basically does what you want an then ask specific questions about modifying it.  Personally I'm not willing to spend too much time on creating a very idiosyncratic citation style if I don't see that it might be helpful to others too.

Comment: @alan-munn - the thing is author-year is the preferred style by referees who are families with the papers by name+year, however, numbered citation are required by an internal fund. The solution I thought of is to combine these. in case it is so problematic, I must type the author-year by hand, and use numbered style. What do you say about the asterisk requirement. Is that even possible? Should I write a separate question for this issue?

Comment: @Different111222 Since you are submitting to different places, there is no need to combine them: that's the beauty of automation.  For documents that require numbered citations, use that style; for author/year, use that style. No need to type anything by hand. The asterisk problem is more tractable, but might be best as a separate question.

Comment: @alan-munn - I think I did not explain myself correctly. I must send numbered citation. However, I can't give up on the author-year style - it would be a mistake. I take your advice and write a separate question for the asterisk. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11325/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-different111222)

Comment: You are [not the first](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141743/35864) to ask for this weird style [BibLaTeX citing style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135011/35864), maybe the answer in the second link can help you. In your case you can choose either `authoryear` or `numeric` as basis and steal some commands from the other to put together your style.

Comment: I would second the request: the [biblatex manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) is very long and detailed, which has meant that i've never managed to get a working  understanding of it.  (i have following several answers here without getting anywhere useful -- though (of course) such a learning strategy is inevitably somewhat patchy ;-).

Comment: For first customisation steps there is [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). As well a a host of questions on this site. Though I have to agree, the documentation is quite full-on.