# biblatex numeric style with author last name?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am currently usign the `numeric` style in biblatex. This gives me the obvious result of `[22]` when I call `\cite{Someone}`. I would like to stick to the `numeric` style but also include the last name in the citation, for example something along the lines of: `[(Someone)22]` or `(Someone)[22]`. My question is two fold:

1. Is this citation style in any way common? I would probably distance myself from it if it is too far from current standards.
2. How would I implement this? I assume the trick lies somewhere in `\DeclareCiteCommand`, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Ad. 1: I personally find this style quite peculiar (and have not seen it anywhere before - but then there are quite a lot of styles out there that I have not seen) as it is neither here (`numeric`) nor there (`authoryear`/`authortitle`).

Comment: See also [BibLaTeX citing style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135011/35864)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can define a new citation command (analogous to [BibLaTeX citing style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135011/35864))

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\morecite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}%
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

If you insist, you can replace the normal `\cite`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}%
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\morecite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}%
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\morecite{westfahl:space} and \morecite{westfahl:frontier}, \morecite{cicero,wilde}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 ... though the output shows why this is a bad style: it loses half the benefit of numeric citations (their unobtrusiveness) and the reader is likely to confuse the label number for a page reference!

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's not as clear as I hoped. Not sure if I should keep this style.