# How to make Author-numeric citation style?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Having been using Author-Year apa style for a while. However, the **numeric** style references-list seems neat.

The issue is that the numeric `\citep{}` only shows [number] in bracket. So I wonder how to twist the numeric citation style like:

`\cite[Johnson:2013]`  ---->  Johnson et al. [19]  (`\textcite{}` can do this job)

`\citep[Johnson:2013]`  ---->  (Johnson et al. [19])

how to make a new command `\textcitep{}` to achieve 2nd style?

```
\usepackage[
  style=numeric,
  backend=biber,
  refsection=chapter,
  uniquename=true,
  uniquelist=false,
  maxcitenames=2, 
  natbib=true ]{biblatex}
```

Comment: [biblatex numeric style with author last name?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165548/35864) does almost what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
  style=numeric,
  backend=biber,
  refsection=chapter,
  uniquename=true,
  uniquelist=false,
  maxcitenames=2,
  natbib=true ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newcommand\textcitep[1]{\mkbibparens{\textcite{#1}}}
\newcommand\textcitesp[1]{\mkbibparens{\textcites{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Text \textcitesp{knuth:ct:c, companion}. See also \textcitep{knuth:ct:d}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this approach severely inhibits `biblatex`'s pre- and postnote abilities (as well as the `\textcites` approach).

Comment: I didn't try to see if there were side effects, I must say. In simple cases it works…

Comment: Definitely, I tried it the usual way via `\DeclareCiteCommand` (that is: steal the definition of the macro that comes closest and modify it). But `\textcite` in its `numeric.cbx` definition is quite convoluted and was stubborn when I added `\mkbibparens` at first. The problem with postnotes and the like is a typical problem of approaches where one has to give the arguments explicitly in a `\newcommand`. It would require some more code to "recode" the argument structure of the macro.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `\cite{}` also works fine for the 1st style. can I redefine the `\citep{}` for 2nd style?

Comment: I guess so, but check for side-effects, just in case. `\citep` is more or less an alias for biblatex's native `\parencite`.

Comment: I think I might have found a side-effect free solution with slightly more code, feel free to have a look and comment!

Answer (score 1):

We can redefine `\textcite`(`s`) to be wrapped in parentheses (quite) easily by

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textcites}[\mkbibparens]{\cbx@textcite}{}
\makeatother
```

If you want a new command `\textcitep` for that we will also have to copy some more definitions from `numeric.cbx` and adapt that.
Then we need

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcitep}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textciteps}[\mkbibparens]{\cbx@textcitep}{}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcitep}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcitep]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textciteps}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textciteps]{\textcitep}{}
\makeatother
```

to create a new `\textcitep` and a new multicite `\textciteps`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  style=numeric,
  backend=biber,
  uniquename=true,
  uniquelist=false,
  maxcitenames=2,
  natbib=true ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcitep}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textciteps}[\mkbibparens]{\cbx@textcitep}{}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcitep}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcitep]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textciteps}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textciteps]{\textcitep}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text \textcites{knuth:ct:c, companion}. See also \textcite{knuth:ct:d}.

Text \textciteps{knuth:ct:c, companion}. See also \textcitep{knuth:ct:d}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Wow! I wouldn't have been able to conceive such an involved code.

Comment: @Bernard Neither was I, this is just a copy of the relevant stuff from `numeric.cbx` with a few `p`s and `\mkbibparens` thrown in...

Comment: That's the way I most often patch default formatting of biblatex: follow the Ariadne's thread of a bib driver and going back through the bibmacros involved. Looks very much like a trail game (not sure it's the right wording in English…)